# A Rational Parameterization of Multiple Simple Expressions (Or the intersection of two rational parameterizations)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

**Context**

I am interested specifically in all rational values of $x$ for which $\sqrt{1-x}$ and $\sqrt{1+x}$ are rational.

In general; however, I am curious if there is a method for taking any number of expressions in the form $\sqrt{n_i \pm x}$ and finding all rational values for x that ensure all of the expressions are rational.

**What I have tried**

I have tried a few different methods:

**Method 1**

I have tried calculating rational parameterizations of both expressions individually by taking the rational point $(0,1)$ and finding the intersection between a line with a rational slope through that point and the graphs individually.

For $y=\sqrt{1-x}$ I used the line $x=t(y-1)$

Plugging this into $y=\sqrt{1-x}$ I get $y=\sqrt{1-t(y-1)}$

By solving this for $y$ (and ultimate $x$) in terms of $t$, I get $x=-t^2-2t$

Similarly for $y=\sqrt{1+x}$ with this method I get $x=t^2+2t$

But I have not been able to parameterize the intersection of these two parameterizations.

**Method 2**

I have tried calculating rational parameterizations of both expressions together by combining them into the system:

$$y=\sqrt{1-x}$$

$$z=\sqrt{1+x}$$

and taking the rational point $(0,1,1)$ and finding the intersection between a line with a rational slope through that point and the surface $(x,\sqrt{1-x},\sqrt{1+x})$.

By this method I get a long and messy formula that does not guarantee rational coordinates.

**Method 3**

I have tried using the same techniques to rationally parameterize $y=\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}$ with a similarly messy result.

**Method 4**

Since $x$ is rational, $x=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are co-prime integers, the expressions above can be rewritten as:

$$\sqrt{1-x}=\sqrt{1-\frac{a}{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{b-a}{b}}$$

$$\sqrt{1+x}=\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{b+a}{b}}$$

For these to be rational either $a$ must contain $b$ as a factor (which is impossible because $a$ and $b$ are defined co-prime) or $b$ must be a square integer $b=c^2$.

I performed a search for all positive integers in certain range that where $\sqrt{c^2-a}$ and $\sqrt{c^2+a}$ are integers to attempt to identify a pattern.

The first few fully reduced fractions (where $a \neq 0$) that I found are:

$$\frac{24}{25},\frac{120}{169},\frac{240}{289},\frac{336}{625},\frac{840}{841},\frac{840}{1369},\frac{720}{1681},\frac{2520}{2809},\frac{1320}{3721},\frac{2016}{4225},\frac{3696}{4225},\frac{5280}{5329},\frac{2184}{7225},\frac{5544}{7225},\frac{6240}{7921},...$$

The denominators (the value of $c$, not $c^2$) seem to correspond directly to the "Ordered hypotenuses (with multiplicity) of primitive Pythagorean triangles" [OEIS A020882](https://oeis.org/A020882) and the numerators to "Common differences in triples of squares in arithmetic progression, that are not a multiples of other triples in (A$198384$, A$198385$, A$198386$)" [OEIS A198438](https://oeis.org/A198438).

With this information, I am unsure how to prove that these sequences will enumerate a full rational parameterization of my two initial expressions without missing any rational points, and how to generate a parameterization of these rational values.

**Final Notes**

Any hints, ideas, or references would be much appreciated!

**Edit**

Thanks to John Omielan and using my techniques above, I have determined that $\sqrt{1-x}$ and $\sqrt{1+x}$ are rational when $x=\frac{4t(t^2-1)}{(t^2+1)^2}$ for all rational values of $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\sqrt{c^2 - a}$ and $\sqrt{c^2 + a}$ to be integers means for some integers $b$ and $d$ you have

$$\sqrt{c^2 - a} = b \implies c^2 - a = b^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$\sqrt{c^2 + a} = d \implies c^2 + a = d^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

\eqref{eq2A} minus \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$2a = d^2 - b^2 \implies a = \frac{d^2 - b^2}{2} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Adding these $2$ equations instead gives

$$2c^2 = b^2 + d^2 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

There are a couple of good answers in Quora's [Are there two squares that when added the sum is twice another square?](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-two-squares-that-when-added-the-sum-is-twice-another-square) that help to solve this. First, Justin Rising's [answer](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-two-squares-that-when-added-the-sum-is-twice-another-square/answer/Justin-Rising) explains

> We start by noting that $a^2 + b^2 = 2c^2$ if and only if $\left(\frac{a}{c\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b}{c\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 = 1$. This means that the point $(\frac{a}{c\sqrt{2}}, \frac{b}{c\sqrt{2}})$ lies on the unit circle. If we rotate it by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians, we get $(\frac{a}{2c} − \frac{b}{2c}, \frac{a}{2c} + \frac{b}{2c})$. Therefore, every solution to the the original equation corresponds to a rational point on the unit circle.

Next, Ben Packer's [answer](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-two-squares-that-when-added-the-sum-is-twice-another-square/answer/Ben-Packer-1) extends this to show that every rational point on the unit circle corresponds to a Pythagorean triple, i.e.,

$$x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Then setting

$$\frac{b}{c} = -\frac{x}{z} + \frac{y}{z} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

$$\frac{d}{c} = \frac{x}{z} + \frac{y}{z} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

gives a solution to \eqref{eq4A}. Note this connection to Pythagorean triples helps to explain your observation of

> The denominators (the value of $c$, not $c^2$) seem to correspond directly to the "Ordered hypotenuses (with multiplicity) of primitive Pythagorean triangles" [OEIS A020882](https://oeis.org/A020882)